# Unable to set up selenium grid with my local machine as hub and microsoft azure VM as node

Tags: selenium, selenium-grid

I tried to search stackoverflow for answer to this question but didn't get the right one. So posting this. Please let me know how to solve this.

I am trying to set up a selenium grid with my local machine as hub. I created a microsoft azure VM and trying to use it as node.

I executed the following command on hub (my local machine) and it started listing on port 4444.

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.53.1.jar -role hub
```

I executed the following command on the VM (node) but it's not getting registered with the hub.

```
java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver="D:\selenium\geckodriver.exe" -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.53.1.jar -role webdriver -hub http://
176.154.37.8:4444/grid/register/ -port 5566
```

I have opened all the required ports on the VM but still it is not working. The logs are shown below.

Can you please check it and let me know what mistake I am doing?

Hub log:

```
E:\>java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.53.1.jar -role hub
```

> 18:40:38.638 INFO - Launching Selenium Grid hub
>
> 2018-06-29 18:40:40.478:INFO::main: Logging initialized @2079ms
>
> 18:40:40.497 INFO - Will listen on 4444
>
> 18:40:40.565 INFO - Will listen on 4444
>
> 2018-06-29 18:40:40.569:INFO:osjs.Server:main: jetty-9.2.z-SNAPSHOT
>
> 2018-06-29 18:40:40.606:INFO:osjsh.ContextHandler:main: Started
>   o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@17211155{/,null,AVAILABLE}
>
> 2018-06-29 18:40:40.636:INFO:osjs.ServerConnector:main: Started
>   ServerConnector@4d85a01a{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:4444}
>
> 2018-06-29 18:40:40.639:INFO:osjs.Server:main: Started @2241ms
>
> 18:40:40.640 INFO - Nodes should register to
>   http://176.154.37.8:4444/grid/register/
>
> 18:40:40.640 INFO - Selenium Grid hub is up and running

Node Log:

```
D:\selenium>java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver="D:\selenium\geckodriver.exe" -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.53.1.jar -role webdriver -hub http://176.154.37.8:4444/grid/register/ -port 5566 -debug
```

> 14:24:05.488 INFO - Launching a Selenium Grid node
>
> 14:24:06.285 DEBUG - CookieSpec selected: default
>
> 14:24:06.301 DEBUG - Auth cache not set in the context
>
> 14:24:06.301 DEBUG - Connection request: [route: {}->myurl:4444][total
>   kept alive: 0; route allocated: 0 of 2000; total allocated: 0 of 2000]
>
> 14:24:06.332 DEBUG - Connection leased: [id: 0][route:
>   {}->myurl:4444][total kept alive: 0; route allocated: 1 of 2000; total
>   allocated: 1 of 2000]
>
> 14:24:06.332 DEBUG - Opening connection {}->myurl:4444
>
> 14:24:06.332 DEBUG - Connecting to /192.168.32.1:4444
>
> 14:24:27.352 DEBUG - http-outgoing-0: Shutdown connection
>
> 14:24:27.352 DEBUG - Connection discarded
>
> 14:24:27.352 DEBUG - Connection released: [id: 0][route:
>   {}->myurl:4444][total kept alive: 0; route allocated: 0 of 2000; total
>   allocated: 0 of 2000]
>
> 14:24:27.352 WARN - error getting the parameters from the hub. The
>   node may end up with wrong timeouts.Connect to 192.168.32.1:4444
>   [/192.168.32.1] failed: Connection timed out: connect
>
> 14:24:27.399 INFO - Java: Oracle Corporation 25.172-b11
>
> 14:24:27.399 INFO - OS: Windows 10 10.0 amd64
>
> 14:24:27.415 INFO - v2.53.1, with Core v2.53.1. Built from revision
>   a36b8b1
>
> 14:24:27.415 INFO - Selenium server running in debug mode.
>
> 14:24:27.415 DEBUG - add component: SocketListener0@0.0.0.0:5566
>
> 14:24:27.446 DEBUG - add component:
>   org.openqa.jetty.http.ResourceCache@12cdcf4
>
> 14:24:27.446 DEBUG - add component:
>   org.openqa.selenium.server.ProxyHandler in HttpContext[/,/]
>
> 14:24:27.446 DEBUG - add component: HttpContext[/,/]
>
> 14:24:27.462 DEBUG - Added HttpContext[/,/] for host *
>
> 14:24:27.462 DEBUG - add component:
>   org.openqa.jetty.http.ResourceCache@ed9d034
>
> 14:24:27.462 DEBUG - added SC{BASIC,null,user,CONFIDENTIAL} at
>   /org/openqa/selenium/tests/html/basicAuth/*
>
> 14:24:27.477 DEBUG - add component:
>   org.openqa.jetty.http.handler.SecurityHandler in
>   HttpContext[/selenium-server,/selenium-server]
>
> 14:24:27.477 DEBUG - add component:
>   org.openqa.selenium.server.StaticContentHandler in
>   HttpContext[/selenium-server,/selenium-server] 14:24:27.477 DEBUG -
>   add component: org.openqa.selenium.server.SessionExtensionJsHandler in
>   HttpContext[/selenium-server,/selenium-server]
>
> 14:24:27.477 DEBUG - add component:
>   org.openqa.selenium.server.htmlrunner.SingleTestSuiteResourceHandler
>   in HttpContext[/selenium-server,/selenium-server]
>
> 14:24:27.477 DEBUG - add component:
>   org.openqa.selenium.server.htmlrunner.SeleniumHTMLRunnerResultsHandler@3891771e
>
> 14:24:27.477 DEBUG - add component:
>   HttpContext[/selenium-server,/selenium-server]
>
> 14:24:27.477 DEBUG - Added
>   HttpContext[/selenium-server,/selenium-server] for host *
>
> 14:24:27.509 INFO - Driver class not found:
>   com.opera.core.systems.OperaDriver
>
> 14:24:27.509 INFO - Driver provider com.opera.core.systems.OperaDriver
>   is not registered
>
> 14:24:27.524 INFO - Driver provider
>   org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriver registration is skipped:
>   registration capabilities Capabilities [{browserName=safari, version=,
>   platform=MAC}] does not match the current platform WIN10
>
> 14:24:27.524 INFO - Driver class not found:
>   org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver
>
> 14:24:27.524 INFO - Driver provider
>   org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver is not registered
>
> 14:24:27.540 DEBUG - add component:
>   org.openqa.jetty.http.ResourceCache@5e57643e
>
> 14:24:27.540 DEBUG - add component:
>   org.openqa.selenium.server.SeleniumDriverResourceHandler in
>   HttpContext[/selenium-server,/selenium-server]
>
> 14:24:27.540 DEBUG - add component:
>   HttpContext[/selenium-server/driver,/selenium-server/driver]
>
> 14:24:27.540 DEBUG - Added
>   HttpContext[/selenium-server/driver,/selenium-server/driver] for host
>   *
>
> 14:24:27.540 DEBUG - add component:
>   org.openqa.jetty.http.ResourceCache@45afc369
>
> 14:24:27.556 DEBUG - add component: WebDriver remote server
>
> 14:24:27.556 DEBUG - add component:
>   org.openqa.jetty.jetty.servlet.HashSessionManager@1e9e725a
>
> 14:24:27.571 DEBUG - add component:
>   org.openqa.jetty.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler@15d9bc04
>
> 14:24:27.571 DEBUG - add component: HttpContext[/wd,/wd]
>
> 14:24:27.571 DEBUG - Added HttpContext[/wd,/wd] for host *
>
> 14:24:27.571 DEBUG - Starting org.openqa.jetty.jetty.Server@2353b3e6
>
> 14:24:27.571 INFO - Version Jetty/5.1.x
>
> 14:24:27.571 DEBUG - LISTENERS: [SocketListener0@0.0.0.0:5566]
>
> 14:24:27.571 DEBUG - HANDLER:
>   {null={/selenium-server/*=[HttpContext[/selenium-server,/selenium-server]], /wd/*=[HttpContext[/wd,/wd]],
>   /selenium-server/driver/*=[HttpContext[/selenium-server/driver,/selenium-server/driver]],
>   /=[HttpContext[/,/]]}}
>
> 14:24:27.571 DEBUG - Starting
>   HttpContext[/selenium-server,/selenium-server]
>
> 14:24:27.571 DEBUG - Init classloader from null,
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@5c647e05 for
>   HttpContext[/selenium-server,/selenium-server]
>
> 14:24:27.571 DEBUG - Started
>   org.openqa.jetty.http.handler.SecurityHandler in
>   HttpContext[/selenium-server,/selenium-server]
>
> 14:24:27.571 DEBUG - Started
>   org.openqa.selenium.server.StaticContentHandler in
>   HttpContext[/selenium-server,/selenium-server]
>
> 14:24:27.571 DEBUG - Started
>   org.openqa.selenium.server.SessionExtensionJsHandler in
>   HttpContext[/selenium-server,/selenium-server]
>
> 14:24:27.571 DEBUG - Started
>   org.openqa.selenium.server.htmlrunner.SingleTestSuiteResourceHandler
>   in HttpContext[/selenium-server,/selenium-server]
>
> 14:24:27.571 DEBUG - Started
>   org.openqa.selenium.server.SeleniumDriverResourceHandler in
>   HttpContext[/selenium-server,/selenium-server]
>
> 14:24:27.571 INFO - Started
>   HttpContext[/selenium-server,/selenium-server]
>
> 14:24:27.571 DEBUG - Starting HttpContext[/wd,/wd]
>
> 14:24:27.571 DEBUG - Init classloader from null,
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@5c647e05 for HttpContext[/wd,/wd]
>
> 14:24:27.571 DEBUG - Starting
>   org.openqa.jetty.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler@15d9bc04
>
> 14:24:27.571 DEBUG - New random session seed
>
> 14:24:27.571 DEBUG - Started holder of class
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DriverServlet
>
> 14:24:27.571 DEBUG - Session scavenger period = 30s
>
> 14:24:27.571 INFO - Started
>   org.openqa.jetty.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler@15d9bc04
>
> 14:24:27.571 INFO - Started HttpContext[/wd,/wd]
>
> 14:24:27.587 DEBUG - Starting
>   HttpContext[/selenium-server/driver,/selenium-server/driver]
>
> 14:24:27.587 DEBUG - Init classloader from null,
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@5c647e05 for
>   HttpContext[/selenium-server/driver,/selenium-server/driver]
>
> 14:24:27.587 INFO - Started
>   HttpContext[/selenium-server/driver,/selenium-server/driver]
>
> 14:24:27.587 DEBUG - Starting HttpContext[/,/]
>
> 14:24:27.587 DEBUG - Init classloader from null,
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@5c647e05 for HttpContext[/,/]
>
> 14:24:27.602 DEBUG - Started org.openqa.selenium.server.ProxyHandler
>   in HttpContext[/,/]
>
> 14:24:27.602 INFO - Started HttpContext[/,/]
>
> 14:24:27.602 INFO - Started SocketListener on 0.0.0.0:5566
>
> 14:24:27.602 INFO - Started org.openqa.jetty.jetty.Server@2353b3e6
>
> 14:24:27.602 INFO - Selenium Grid node is up and ready to register to
>   the hub
>
> 14:24:27.634 DEBUG - Using the json request :
>   {"class":"org.openqa.grid.common.RegistrationRequest","configuration":{"role":"webdriver","debug":"","remoteHost":"http://10.0.1.4:5566","hubHost":"192.168.32.1","hubPort":4444,"url":"http://10.0.1.4:5566","proxy":"org.openqa.grid.selenium.proxy.DefaultRemoteProxy","hub":"myurl:4444/grid/register/","port":5566,"host":"10.0.1.4","maxSession":5,"registerCycle":5000,"register":true},"capabilities":[{"browserName":"firefox","seleniumProtocol":"WebDriver","maxInstances":5,"platform":"WIN10"},{"browserName":"chrome","seleniumProtocol":"WebDriver","maxInstances":5,"platform":"WIN10"},{"browserName":"internet
>   explorer","seleniumProtocol":"WebDriver","maxInstances":1,"platform":"WINDOWS"}]}
>
> 14:24:27.634 INFO - Starting auto registration thread. Will try to
>   register every 5000 ms.
>
> 14:24:27.634 INFO - Registering the node to the hub:
>   myurl:4444/grid/register
>
> 14:24:27.634 DEBUG - CookieSpec selected: default
>
> 14:24:27.634 DEBUG - Auth cache not set in the context
>
> 14:24:27.650 DEBUG - Connection request: [route: {}->myurl:4444][total
>   kept alive: 0; route allocated: 0 of 2000; total allocated: 0 of 2000]
>   14:24:27.650 DEBUG - Connection leased: [id: 1][route:
>   {}->myurl:4444][total kept alive: 0; route allocated: 1 of 2000; total
>   allocated: 1 of 2000]
>
> 14:24:27.650 DEBUG - Opening connection {}->myurl:4444
>
> 14:24:27.650 DEBUG - Connecting to /192.168.32.1:4444
>
> 14:24:31.149 INFO - Shutting down...

Thank you,
subbu.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly you should start the node with `-role node` and not `-role webdriver`.

Take a look at [Selenium Grid Documentation](https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/07_selenium_grid.jsp)

Also make sure that in logs the node connects to the correct hub ip address, maybe something wrong is configured at a network level.

If you want to check connectivity from node to hub, the easiest option is running:

```
telnet <HUB-IP-ADDR/DNS> 4444
```

If you get "connected", then you have a connectivity.